# How can I reduce the size of Google closure library for deployment?

Tags: javascript, google-closure

The Google closure library is huge, how can I reduce size of it to deploy it with my project?
It contains lots JavaScript files  and whole bunch of resources, in total 14mb, would be nice to know what can I do to optimize it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the library (as is) is intended to be used in production. Use the [**Closure Compiler**](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/).

See also *Shrinking Code with ClosureBuilder and the Closure Compiler* in the [Google Closure documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/closurebuilder).

Answer (score 2):

It isn't a standalone library.  It is intended to be used in parts.  For simple hacking you can however use http://www.programmingclosure.com/closure-lite/